# Populating Google Analytics tags with dynamic information using JavaScript and JSP

Tags: java, javascript, analytics

I am updating a JSP file to create a virtual pageview within Google Analytics. I can see the trackPageView event fire when I click on the right link, but the information I'm trying to pull in dynamically isn't appearing and I'm not sure why.

I have tried a two approaches. My first attempt was to put a  statement directly within the GA tag (which always work for _trackEvent).  That doesn't generate any information.

The second idea I had was to create a variable in JavaScript with a  and then use that variable in the GA code.  The problem with this is that I don't know JavaScript very well (or JSP for that matter...learning on the job) and I'm not sure of the correct way to pull in that variable since it's already within the '' from the GA code.  Here is my code (currentPDP in the _trackPageView call should be dynamically populated):

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var currentPDP = <c:out value="${link.key}" /> [];
                    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('a.online').click(function (e) {
                            $('#retail-modal').modal();
                            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-33021136-1']); 
                            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/vp/currentPDP/retailer links page']);
                            (function() {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                  })();
                            return false;

                        });
                    });

                </script>
```

Any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated. The ultimate goal is to add a specific value (product name) from the current page the person is viewing into the Google Analytics tag so we know what page they were on.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this one by updating a JavaScript function in a different .JSP file that was sending data to this one. I had to add the corresposing parameters to the .JSP file and then I was able to pull in the data I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In a JSP you could just insert an "echo" tag like this:

```
<%= jspVariable %>
```

In the JavaScript code you can concatenate a JavaScript variable onto another by doing this:

```
var url = 'http://mydomain.com/other/stuff';
existingVar += url;
```

What is the specific line of Google Analytics code you are wanting to add to?

Taking a guess that its this line:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/vp/currentPDP/retailer links page']);
```

Say you want to replace **retailer links page** you would do the following for a Java variable:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/vp/currentPDP/<%= jspVariableHoldingPageURLLink %>']);
```

Or with Javascript

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/vp/currentPDP/' + 'javaScriptVariableHoldingPageURLLink' ]);
```